# Subtract one circle from another

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to substract the green circle from the white circle, but the program only has one solution which seems to fail. Can you help me please?

[image: What i want to do]

[image: The 'solution']
other pathfinder features like add or overlapp doesn't do anything

Comment: .. subtract front shape...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "Subtract Front Shape" button in the properties panel appears to produce an unexpected result, as shown by the OP's screenshot. I can also reproduce this (in version 24.7) and it looks like it could be a potential bug.

I've tried to google this to see if someone has reported it, but there are so many complaints about the the properties panel, trying to find the right one is almost impossible.

A workaround:

Select both shape layers, and do *Layers > Combine Shapes > Subtract Front Shape*.

This boolean operation will cause the resulting shape to fill with green (from the top shape), but you can just change the shape fill to white.

Comment: Must be a bug.. I can't reproduce this in the (older) version I'm using. Subtract Front Shape works fine here.

Comment: @Scott - yeah. I don't have an older version to test. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.